# PHP: $_GET['url'] does not fetch the value from URL after Cleaning the URL with .htaccess and directing to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem not being able to access other parts of the website except the index page. I used htaccess to redirect all requests to the index.php but i get the error: **Notice: Undefined index: url in /home4/amberrec/public_html/portal/app/core/app.php on line 52**

**This is my .htaccess code.**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**This is my app.php code**

```
class App 
{
    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];
    
    function __construct()
    {
        // get the split url
        $url = $this->split_url(); // url[0]=controller, url[1]=method, the rest is params

        // create the path to the controllers folder
        $path_to_controller = __DIR__ . '../../controllers/';

        // check if the url[0] which is the controller exists/
        if (file_exists($path_to_controller . strtolower($url[0] . ".php"))) 
        {
            // set the controller if it exist
            $this->controller = strtolower($url[0]);
        
            //unset it
            unset($url[0]);
        }

        // require the class and create a new instance
        require $path_to_controller . $this->controller . '.php';
        $this->controller = new $this->controller();

        // check if the url[1] which is the controller's method exists/
        if (isset($url[1]))
        {
            if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) 
            {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        // store the rest of the params if available
        $this->params = array_values($url);

        // call the method of the contoller
        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    // Gets the url link and splits into an array
    function split_url() : array
    {
        return explode('/', filter_var(trim($url,"/"), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // test to get controller name
    function get_controller_name()
    {
        return $this->controller;
    }
    
    function showURI()
    {
        echo $this->url;
    }
}
```

**This is my index.php**

```
session_start();

require __DIR__ . '/app/init.php';

$app = new App();
```

This is my config code

```
/*root and asset paths*/

$path = str_replace("\\", "/",PROTOCAL ."://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . __DIR__  . "/");
$path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], "", $path);

define('ROOT', trim(str_replace("app/core", '', $path), '/'));
define('ASSETS', str_replace("app/core", "public/assets", $path));
```

**This is my folder structure**

- app

  - controllers
  - models
  - views
  - core

    - app.php
    - config.php
- public

  - assets
- .htaccess
- index.php

Comment: What I'm going to say doesn't solve your problem and I don't know why you're trying to do this, but I tried to build a basic MVC structure for a project, and over time I needed to add more functionality, spending more time with the framework than the project in itself. So unless you really need to do this from scratch, study Laravel which will be much more advantageous for you.

Comment: The error you are quoting does not appear to relate to the code you have posted? There is no `$_GET['url']` in any of the code you posted? "not being able to access other parts of the website except the index page" - by "index page" I assume you are referring to the document root? But it should be the other way round... when you request the doc root then the `url` URL param will not be set (yet you don't get the E_NOTICE for that request). You should be checking that that index/var exists before attempting to use it and defaulting otherwise, so you should never get that E_NOTICE.

Comment: The split_url() function references a non-existent variable $url.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have $this->url. Try add:

```
protected $url =[];
```

then

```
$url = $this->split_url();
$this->url = $url;
```

or call the function with $url

```
showURI($url);
function showURI($url) {
 echo $url[0].$url[1];
 //var_dump($url);
}
```

IMPORTAN you cant echo of array like

```
echo $this->url;
```